# Why isn't setup.py dependency_links doing anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have an entry in my `setup.py` to install a package not hosted on PyPi, that must be compiled using setup.py as it is a C extension. It's not installing when I run `python setup.py install`, I've checked the logs and I have no idea why.

```
dependency_links = ['git+https://github.com/liamzebedee/scandir.git#egg=scandir-0.1'],
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out that as well as a `dependency_links` line, I also needed to add the name of the package in an `install_requires` line, like so:

```
dependency_links = ['git+https://github.com/liamzebedee/scandir.git#egg=scandir-0.1'],
install_requires = ['scandir'],
```